# Nested arrays won't display contents

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, json

I've been diving into API and inevitably ran into JSON files. I really like how PHP arrays can return JSON format and the info within be used for displaying info about something or someone inside a web page. (Began with stipeAPI which is awesome!)

The problem(s): when I create an array within an array and try to `print_r()` the contents, I get this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => cx_id_00002
    [1] => karikanaan08@gmail.com
    [2] =>   vsv
    [3] => NULL
    [4] => Array
        (
            [] => sv
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [] => FC
        )

)
```

[4] => array only has 1 item so it displays fine, but [5] => array has several items which do not display. when I var_dump($_POST) everything appears just fine. here is my code:

```
<?php
$customers = "";
  $id = "";
  $email = "";
  $description = "";
  $default_source = "";
  $metadata = "";
    $color_preference = "";
  $cards = "";
    $card_id = "";
    $card_number = "";
    $card_name = "";
    $card_exp_month = "";
    $card_exp_year = "";
    $card_address_line1 = "";
    $card_address_line2 = "";
    $card_address_city = "";
    $card_address_state = "";
    $card_address_zip = "";
    $card_address_country = "";

    $colNum = 1;

    $number = 1; // Initiallizes the varible $number as an empty string

$data = file_get_contents("stripeInfo.json");
$data = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($data, true);

echo '<pre>';

print_r($_POST);
$info = json_encode($_POST);
print_r($info);

echo '</pre>';

?>

<style type="text/css">

  legend {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12pt;
  }

  input {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
  }

  textarea {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
  }

  label  {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 130px;
  }

  fieldset {
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
  }

  #submit {
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 200px;
  }
</style>

<!-- form to be displayed -->

<form action="#" method="POST">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Customer Account Details:</legend>

  <!-- hidden input type - USE "required" for required inputs -->
  <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value='<?php sprintf('cx_id_%05d', $number++) ?>' ><br>

  <label for="email">Email:</label>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="" placeholder="Enter your email"><br>

  <label for="description">Describe Yourself:</label>
  <textarea name="description" id="description" class="">
  </textarea><br>

  <!-- hidden input type -->
  <input type="hidden" name="default_source" id="default_source" class="" value="NULL"><br>

  <label for="metadata[0][color_preference]">Favorite Color:</label>
  <input type="text" name="color_preference" id="color_preference" class="" placeholder="Favorite Color"><br>
</fieldset>

<br><br><br>

<fieldset>
  <legend>Edit/Update Payment Information</legend>

  <!-- hidden input type -->
  <input type="hidden" name="cards[0]" class="" value="NULL" ><br>


  <label for="cards[1][card_number]">Card Number:</label>
  <input type="text" maxlength="16" name="cards[1][card_number]" id="card_number" class="" placeholder="Enter Your Card Number"><br>

  <label for="card_name">Name on Card:</label>
  <input type="text" name="cards[2][card_name]" id="card_name" class="" placeholder="Name On Card" ><br>

  <label for="card_exp_month">Expiration Month:</label>
  <input type="text" max-length="2" name="cards[3][card_exp_month]" id="card_exp_month" class="" placeholder="Exp Date ex. 02" ><br>

  <label for="cards[3][card_exp_year">Expiration Year:</label>
  <input type="text" max-length="4" name="cards[4][card_exp_year]" id="card_exp_year" class="" placeholder="Expiration Year"><br>

  <label for="address_line1">Address Line 1:</label>
  <input type="text" name="cards[5][address_line1]" id="address_line1" class="" placeholder="Address Line 1" value="" ><br>

  <label for="address_line2">Address Line 2:</label>
  <input type="text" name="cards[6][address_line2]" id="address_line2" class="" placeholder="Address Line 1" value="" ><br>

  <label for="address_city">City:</label>
  <input type="text" name="cards[7][address_city]" id="address_city" class="" placeholder="City"><br>

  <label for="address_state">State:</label>
  <input type="text" name="cards[8][address_state]" id="address_state" class="" placeholder="State" ><br>

  <label for="address_zip">Zip:</label>
  <input type="text" max-length="5" name="cards[9][address_zip]" id="address_zip" class="" placeholder="Zip"><br>

  <label for="address_country">Country:</label>
  <input type="text" name="cards[10][address_country]" id="address_country" class="" placeholder="Country"><br>
</fieldset>
<br><br>
  <button id="submit" class="" name="submit">Edit/Update Account Details</button>
</form>

<?php

$customers = array(
  $id = sprintf('cx_id_%05d', $number++), // $data['customers'][0]['id'];
  $email = htmlentities($_POST['email']), // $data['customers'][0]['email'];
  $description = htmlentities($_POST['description']), // $data['customers'][0]['description'];
  $default_source = htmlentities($_POST['default_source']), // $data['customers'][0]['default_source'];
  $metadata = array(
    $color_preference => htmlentities($_POST['color_preference'])
  ),
    // $data['customers'][0]['metadata'];
    // = $metadata['color_preference'];
  $cards = array(
    $card_id => sprintf('cx_id_%05d', $number++), // $data['customers'][0]['cards']; // = $cards[0]['id'];
    $card_number => htmlentities($_POST['cards'][1]['card_number']), // = $cards[0]['number'];
    $card_name => htmlentities($_POST['cards'][2]['card_name']), // $cards[0]['name'];
    $card_exp_month => htmlentities($_POST['cards'][3]['card_exp_month']), // $cards[0]['exp_month'];
    $card_exp_year => htmlentities($_POST['cards'][4]['card_exp_year']), // $cards[0]['exp_year'];
    $card_address_line1 => htmlentities($_POST['cards'][5]['address_line1']), // $cards[0]['address_line1'];
    $card_address_line2 => htmlentities($_POST['cards'][6]['address_line2']), // $cards[0]['address_line2'];
    $card_address_city => htmlentities($_POST['cards'][7]['address_city']), // $cards[0]['address_city'];
    $card_address_state => htmlentities($_POST['cards'][8]['address_state']), // $cards[0]['address_state'];
    $card_address_zip => htmlentities($_POST['cards'][9]['address_zip']), // $cards[0]['address_zip'];
    $card_address_country => htmlentities($_POST['cards'][10]['address_country']), // $cards[0]['address_country'];
  ),
);

echo '<pre>';

print_r($customers);

echo 'My email is ' . $email . " and my card number is " . $card_number;
echo '</pre>';
/*
$customers = array(
  "id" => $id,
  "email" => $email,
  "description" => $description,
  "default_source" => $default_source,
  "metadata" => $metadata = array(
    "color_preference" => $color_preference),
  "cards" => $cards = array(
    "id" => $card_id,
    "number" => $card_number,
    "name" => $card_name,
    "exp_month" => $card_exp_month,
    "exp_year" => $card_exp_year,
    "address_line1" => $card_address_line1,
    "address_line2" => $card_address_line2,
    "address_city" => $card_address_city,
    "address_state" => $card_address_state,
    "address_zip" => $card_address_zip,
    "address_country" => $card_address_country),
);
*/
$myJson = json_encode($customers);
var_dump($myJson);

 ?>
```

I know it's messy right now. I am just trying to get a grasp on JSON/PHP interaction and how to best implement this into my site.

**My goal:** to make a JSON file out of a PHP script which goes something like this:

```
$customers = array(
    $id => "incremented ID",
    $email => "$_POST['whatever the user puts in']", etc!
```

Ideally I would save this into a JSON file and be able to use user input data for my site. I know that I am getting close, but I just feel like right now i'm at a loss.

1. Get info within nested arrays (arrays within arrays) to display, and
2. How can i set the values of a KEY / VALUE pair to be whatever the user puts in?

[EDIT!] : AND NOW I HAVE THIS! PLEASE HELP!

```
{   "part_1":{      
      "section_1":"editors_and_enviorments",
      "section_2":"working_backwards",
      "section_3":"prep_work",
      "section_4":{
         "section_4.1":"career_facts",
         "section_4.2":"encouraging_word"

}

},
   "0":{      
     "part_2 ":{
         "section_1":"html5",
         "section_2":"css3",
         "section_3":"javaScript",
         "section_4":"jQuery_and_UI",
         "section_5":"php7",
         "section_6":"mySql",
         "section_7":"bootstrap",
         "section_8":"apis_and_ajax",
         "section_9":"json",
         "section_10":"stripeApi"

},
      "part_3":{
         "section_1":"final_project_info",
         "section_2":"mobileApp"

}

}
}
```

And I am using App.js - I want to loop through all the sections as `<li>` within a `<ul>` ... i know it's possible, but how?

Thanks.

Comment: if its php you can use a var_dump() , to verify it it actually has the data. because print_r is supposed to get you the nested arrays too.

Comment: add the output from var_dump

Comment: @Toby_Allen: what do you mean, "add the input" ?

Comment: how do i do that?